# How to set up wireless access on a Cisco router

Tags: router, bridge, iptv

I've set up my 877W according to the configuration listed in this forum post:

[IPTV over Cisco 877](http://omgili.com/jmp/jHIAmI4hxg91AAFr2hsw6VdzG5ATUxxWdzykgS480E..gwF6MUXHp0abDhBpC0FhiY5Xnd_Gv9NISo921wXKAkVYRWPwqKiMmQj5Ilq_olHN5_c.8U2SYUPjBGuTDUW6A2doijnoj1T0Wsx197YXL473vZHUFCn6sMGUlCEfUjTf8DSLMLY5KZAd2YWaPGTk45mmmlR3kVZt2B85XaYeTw--) (It's the working configuration at the bottom of the post)

Note that I have an 877W, so it also has a wireless radio. Now, I've gotten the whole setup to work, so IPTV is working, and I can access the internet via the ethernet ports.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to allow access via the `dot11radio` interface. I've gathered that I basically need to create a bridge group, and bridge the radio to the internet VLAN. However, when I add a `bridge-group 2` command to VLAN1, it seems to take down the whole internet VLAN. (The IPTV continues to work.) This makes the router itself inaccessible (I've got a laptop, so no serial) and I end up having to reboot the router.

Can anyone tell me how to

1. Allow wireless access to the internet (preferably with WEP, to match
   my old router)
2. Determine what makes the router inaccessible when I add the new
   bridge group
3. Forward the IPTV traffic onto a machine on my internet VLAN